# Full screen app on one monitor, Desktop on other

Tags: finder, display, high-sierra, fullscreen

I want to use Terminal in full screen on one monitor while having the desktop accessable on the other. pressing the green button in terminal fills screen 1 with terminal (good), but the other is blank (bad). It would be nice if the other were the desktop or another app.

To sum it up, this is how is is for me now:

```
Screen 1 | Screen 2
-------------------
Terminal |  Blank
```

When Terminal is fullscreen, the other monitor becomes blank i.e. nothing on it.

```
Screen 1 | Screen 2
-------------------
 Blank   | Terminal
```

The same rule applies regardless of what monitor Terminal is on.

This happens to any and all apps, not just Terminal.

I want it to look like this:

```
Screen 1 | Screen 2
-------------------
Terminal | Desktop
```

or:

```
Screen 1 | Screen 2
-------------------
Desktop  | Terminal
```

or another example:

```
Screen 1 | Screen 2
-------------------
 Safari  |  Pages
```

Ideas?

High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: Could you please send a screenshot because your question is not very clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: System preferences > displays. One should be the desktop, the one with the bar indicating the menu. When you know which is desktop, then open the desired app on the other. Unless I’m misunderstanding your question.

Comment: @DaktaMoriamé A screenshot is difficult with two monitors and will not convey my message very well. I have edited my question to re-explain. Hope this helps

Comment: @bjbk Thanks but that is different. I have edited my question to re-explain. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that "Displays have separate Spaces" is checked:

`System Preferences > Mission Control > Displays have separate Spaces`

This should fix the blank screen issue.

[image: Misson Control System Preferences]